# Tell <%= ... %> not to add a space

Tags: phoenix-framework

I use the following code in a template to render a date:

```
<% if job.end_month do %>
  <%= "#{job.end_month}/" %>
<% end %>
<%= "#{job.end_year}" %>
```

This results in `3/ 2014` and not in `3/2014`. How can I force Phoenix not to add a space after `"#{job.end_month}/"`?

Comment: I'd write this as `<%= if job.end_month, do: "#{job.end_month}/" %><%= job.end_year %>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to create an external helper that did this for you:
e.g.

```
def job_string(%Job{end_month: nil}), do: job.end_year
def job_string(job), do: "#{job.end_month}/#{job.end_year}"
```

Then just use that in your view:

```
<%= job_string(job) %>
```

Alternatively if you don't want to do all that and would prefer a messier sort of look:

```
<% if job.end_month do %>
  <%= "#{job.end_month}/#{job.end_year}" %>
<% else %>
  <%= "#{job.end_year}" %>
<% end %>
```